# an animation of an object moving randomly on a computer screen to reduce eye strain?

Tags: eye, computers

Given that it is not natural for human vision to stare for a long time at still objects (a computer display, that is), would an animation of an object moving randomly across the screen (much like in screensavers) help relieve eye-strain?

This whole idea occurred to me when I was a browsing a web site with some advertising effects of a couple of tiny animated butterflies moving randomly across the screen. Surprisingly, this did not seem to interfere with my comfort of reading the page and I even felt as if it were relaxing my eyes. But this has been only a one-time and very short experience to infer any reliable conclusions from it.